# Validation in GO "ozzo-validation"

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm nob in GO :) just try to create simple `crud` throw it using `gin` and plugin called [`ozzo-validation`](https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation)

My code:

```
package models

import (
    validation "github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Post struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(255);"`
    Desc string `gorm:"type:varchar(500);"`
}

type PostData struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Desc string `json:"desc"`
}

func (p PostData) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&p,
        validation.Field(&p.Name, validation.Required, validation.Length(5, 20)),
        validation.Field(&p.Desc, validation.Required),
    )
}
```

PostController:

```
package controllers

import (
    "curd/app/models"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func Store(c *gin.Context) {
    // Validate Input
    var post models.PostData
    err := post.Validate()
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

```
{
  "name": "sdfsdfsfsdf"
}
```

The problem is once I submit the above JSON data from the postman the validation gives me this in terminal :

```
desc: cannot be blank; name: cannot be blank.
```

Comment: `var post models.PostData; <-- decode hre  -->;    err := post.Validate()` you have to decode the post data to the post value before validatiing it. https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#bind-query-string-or-post-data

Comment: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation

Comment: @mh-cbon can you please provide an example of decodeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to decode the data from the HTTP request into the struct before you can perform validation. The validation errors you're seeing are a product of calling `Validate()` on a fresh instance (with zero values in every field) of your `Post` struct. Try [this](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation).

```golang
func Store(c *gin.Context) {
    var post models.PostData
    // This will infer what binder to use depending on the content-type header.
    if err := c.ShouldBind(&post); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }
    // Validate Input
    err := post.Validate()
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: This means the decode data from a request I always should put this big if before the validation! 